# JvTreeView and JvCheckTreeView checkbox notification

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, jvcl

I have set a `JvTreeView.CheckBoxes` to `True`, and the check boxes are displayed and working as expected, but on Windows XP SP3 and below, the `OnNodeCheckedChange` event is not fired. I googled a little, and found [this issue on JVCL issue tracker](http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/view.php?id=5119), but I can not apply it to the latest JVCL release (Version 3.47). Has anyone any fix for the check box event?

---

Update: The event is fired when I change the check box using space bar, but is not fired when I *click* on the check box.

Comment: You've hit exactly the same issue as you linked, but the proposed implementation is there as the [`NeedCheckStateEmulation`](http://jvcl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jvcl/trunk/jvcl/run/JvComCtrls.pas?view=markup) function, and now the check box emulation won't be used only on Windows Vista up with ComCtl v.6.0. In case of your Windows XP you can't meet the Windows version condition so the mentioned function must return True and the check box support should be emulated.

Comment: @TLama even if I modify `NeedSimulation()` to always return `True`, the emulation is not performed as it should. The event is not fired when selecting the check box with mouse.

Comment: That can happen because your application probably uses the unit pre-compiled at the JVCL installation time (`..\jvcl\lib\dXX\JvComCtrls.dcu`), if so, it's not enough to just modify the source (`JvComCtrls.pas`) and re-build your application. I've made a short test for check box emulation but the `OnNodeCheckedChange` event is fired correctly.

Comment: @TLama I have added `JvComCtrls.pas` to my project. So I'm sure it's compiled with the rest of my project. Which version of Windows are you testing this on?

Comment: On Windows 7, that's why I've had to modify the `NeedCheckStateEmulation` function to return only True. But only adding the unit to your project doesn't guarantee, the unit will actually be compiled. Default JVCL installation adds the `..\jvcl\lib\dXX` path (where the *.dcus are stored) to your environment `Library path` options, so the compiler might take already compiled unit from there.

Comment: @TLama On Windows 7, the check boxes are handled by the OS natively. When a check box is selected (or cleared), I guess a `NM_TVSTATEIMAGECHANGING` message is dispatched. But on XP, the control needs to handle `NM_CLICK` and `NM_RCLICK`

Comment: I know, and that's why I've had to modify the `NeedCheckStateEmulation` function to return only True. If you look at how the `PostCheckStateChanged` message is sent (the message handler of this custom message fires the `OnNodeCheckedChange` event), you will see, that even when the `NM_TVSTATEIMAGECHANGING` notification is received, that message is not sent when `NeedCheckStateEmulation` returns True, so in fact, the `NM_TVSTATEIMAGECHANGING` notification is ignored when you return True from `NeedCheckStateEmulation`.

Comment: @TLama I rebuilt the JvStdCtrls package, but the check boxes aren't working as they should. I'm a little interested in the fact that they behave when I use the keyboard; but I can't understand what's the difference between keyboard and mouse events. BTW, I'm using Windows 2003 SP2.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18359/discussion-between-tlama-and-iman-biglari)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a [`discussion`](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18359/discussion-between-tlama-and-iman-biglari) we've had I know you've used RTL reading for your `JvTreeView` and I've added that you should include also the [`TVS_RTLREADING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760013%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#TVS_RTLREADING) style to the control styles. So, here is how to do it in a late control styling (which you have used):

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetWindowLong(JvTreeView1.Handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(
    JvTreeView1.Handle, GWL_STYLE) or TVS_RTLREADING);
  SetWindowLong(JvTreeView1.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE, GetWindowLong(
    JvTreeView1.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL or WS_EX_RIGHT);
end;
```

The problem with the control notification is in coordinates mapping (see [`this answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13019312/960757) why it happens). As a fix to the [`JvComCtrls.pas`](http://jvcl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jvcl/trunk/jvcl/run/JvComCtrls.pas?view=markup&pathrev=13441) source you can replace the `ScreenToClient` point mapping on line 3094 with the following:

```
MapWindowPoints(0, Handle, Point, 1);
```

in the [`JvComCtrls.pas`](http://jvcl.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jvcl/trunk/jvcl/run/JvComCtrls.pas?view=markup&pathrev=13441) unit in the `CNNotify` method it will look like:

```
3071  procedure TJvTreeView.CNNotify(var Msg: TWMNotify);
....  ...
3091    inherited;
3092    if Windows.GetCursorPos(Point) then
3093    begin
3094      MapWindowPoints(0, Handle, Point, 1);
3095      case Msg.NMHdr.code of
....  ...
```